# An adjective to describe something a person can dance to?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

For instance, we can say:
*the music I can dance to*, *the song I can dance to*, *the beat I can dance to*.

Is there a way to communicate the same thought using this format:
*[adjective] music*, *[adjective] song*, *[adjective] beat*?

Comment: How about **dance music**?

Comment: I'm not sure. A song doesn't have to be specifically designed for dancing, but I still might want to dance to it? **Dance music** sounds more like **music for dancing to**.

I also realized **danceable** is a thing, but my spellchecker is highlighting it.

Comment: @cronaut - not sure about yout spellchecker, but danceable is a real word: https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=K-szW-q1LYTjsAeQs7uIAQ&q=danceable+meaning+&oq=danceable+meaning+&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..0i22i30l5.130599.136559..136851...0....426.2912.0j17j4-1......0....1.......3..0j41j46j0i10i67j0i131j0i67j0i10j0i30j0i19j0i22i30i19.xQdsprSeJNE%3D

Comment: damn funky? pop? bit vague this question...

Comment: Who cares what the song/music is designed/intended for? If you can dance to it, it is dance music. Nobody says "danceable music" despite the answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I am not alone: ***Danceable music***  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22danceable%20music%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en - ***Danceable song*** https://www.google.com/search?q=%22danceable%20song%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en - ***Danceable beat*** https://www.google.com/search?q=%22danceable%20beat%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en - ***Danceable*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=danceable&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdanceable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user110518 I didn't realise that, but this is not a vernacular site. Is **danceable** a quality of the song, or of the person hearing it?

Comment: @WeatherVane - there is nothing  vernacular about “danceable”, it’s  regular English language.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - I was thinking along the lines of articulating "this music (or even a set of sounds) evokes the urge to move my body as it is playing, regardless of its genre, style, or origin" with an adjective as precisely as possible.

Comment: there are many music genres and many types of dance, so you might not find a single adjective to cover all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Danceable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/danceable)***

> appropriate for or conducive to dancing:
>
> - danceable music, danceable song etc.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: **Danceable** sounds a little off to me, because the act of dancing cannot be applied to the song itself. I feel tempted to insert "to" in the middle of it (to form __"dance-to-able"__). However, I can't think of any better substitutes, and it does appear in several dictionaries. I'll stick to it until (and if) a better word shows up!